# Let's Encrypt Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

**■Background**

trying to get SSL through Let's Encrypt

**■Issue**

As run the code below,

```
sudo certbot --apache -d hogehoge.com
```

I got the port 80 error

```
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
```

[image]

and unable to resolve this error

**■What I have tried**

have set up the port 80

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

add the description in the file.

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@hogehoge
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName hogehoge
</VirtualHost>
```

but I still got the same error.

would you kindly tell me the cause and how to make it work?

Comment: Can you share the full httpd.conf file? (`egrep -v ‘#|^$’ /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`). This may help us to see what is your problem. Thanks.

Comment: `ServerName hogehoge` - I assume that's the correct complete domain name, just redacted here? You had `hogehoge.com` above and they'd need to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Default command "sudo certbot renew" error on localhost

(1)Uninstall certbot

(2)Reinstall certbot

(3)Sudo certbot certonly

(4)Select option 1, spin up temporary web server

(5)Ensure port 80 is accessible from outside, port forwarding in router

(6) Ensure all services using port 80 are stopped

Try

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.well-known/acme-challenge

[Enabling HTTPS on a Single Instance Beanstalk application: Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837725/enabling-https-on-a-single-instance-beanstalk-application-unable-to-find-a-virt)