# How to fix Cerbot error 'Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80' after Apache Update?

Tags: apache, vhosts, certbot

I have updated Apache from 2.4.6 to 2.4.5x quite recently.

### Now `certbot renew --dry-run` tells me that Apache is not listening on port 80

From */var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log*

```
PluginError: Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.

2022-04-27 13:00:18,010:ERROR:certbot._internal.renewal:All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
2022-04-27 13:00:18,011:ERROR:certbot._internal.renewal:  /etc/letsencrypt/live/co2-avatar.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
```

But I have a `<VirtualHost>` in my apache config, which contains all requested domains as *ServerName/ServerAlias*. I have doublechecked with `netstat` that Apache is listening on port 80.

Here is the config file:

```
# redirect everything from http to https
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    ServerName co2-avatar.com
    ServerAlias sustainable-data-platform.de
    ServerAlias co2-avatar.de
    ServerAlias co2-avatar.eu
    ServerAlias co2-avatar.org
    ServerAlias co2avatar.com
    ServerAlias co2avatar.de
    ServerAlias co2avatar.eu
    ServerAlias co2avatar.org
    ServerAlias git.sustainable-data-platform.org
    ServerAlias gitlab.sustainable-data-platform.org
    ServerAlias hp-cockpit.com
    ServerAlias hp-cockpit.de
    ServerAlias hp-cockpit.eu
    ServerAlias hp-cockpit.org
    ServerAlias hpcockpit.com
    ServerAlias hpcockpit.de
    ServerAlias hpcockpit.eu
    ServerAlias hpcockpit.org
    ServerAlias stop-fossil.de
    ServerAlias stop-fossil.org
    ServerAlias stopfossil.de
    ServerAlias stopfossil.org
    ServerAlias sustainable-building-platform.com
    ServerAlias sustainable-building-platform.de
    ServerAlias sustainable-building-platform.eu
    ServerAlias sustainable-building-platform.org
    ServerAlias sustainable-data-platform.com
    ServerAlias sustainable-data-platform.eu
    ServerAlias sustainable-data-platform.org
    ServerAlias sustainabledataplatform.com
    ServerAlias sustainabledataplatform.de
    ServerAlias sustainabledataplatform.eu
    ServerAlias sustainabledataplatform.org
    ServerAlias test.co2avatar.org
    ServerAlias test.hp-cockpit.org
    ServerAlias wp-cockpit.de
    ServerAlias wp-cockpit.eu
    ServerAlias wp-cockpit.org
    ServerAlias wpcockpit.eu
    ServerAlias wpcockpit.org

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/webServer-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/webServer-access_log" combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.well-known/acme-challenge
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

There might be something wrong with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.well-known/acme-challenge` (which [is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080658/2092322)), but how can I debug this? Are there more detailed log files from *certbot* or *letsencrypt*.

When run the `renew` or when I want to add some domains to my certificate, I indeed do not see any access in my Apache logfiles. So I am not sure, what I am doing wrong here and how to check, what actually happens on their side (*Simulating renewal of an existing certificate for sustainable-data-platform.org and 40 more domains*). Which is differently when I run `curl -v -X GET http://co2-avatar.com/.well-known/acme-challenge` on my machine. I get at least a 301 for this and an entry in the Apache logfile on my server.

Is there any other hint for using *certbot* with Apache 4.2.53?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling your site using then try reinstalling cert

> sudo a2ensite [site conf name]